# Using C99 features for a cross platform application

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc, c99

I am writing a new project in C and I am wondering is it a good practice to use C99 features? I know it will work with GCC and not with MSVC. So I have to use something like MinGW in Windows to get the compile. Are there any other issues?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you can find a C99 compliant compiler for any reasonable platform.
So yes - go ahead and use C99.
Being standard-compliant is always good practice.

Answer (score 3):

C99 is now 13 years old, and MS have made it clear repeatedly that they are not interested in modern C development in VS.  Fortunately, there are several other compiler toolchains available for Windows, and those support C99 / C11 / future revisions of the standard.

There are some micro-controllers that lack C99 development tools, but you are probably not targeting them if you're doing "cross platform application" development.  Essentially all mainstream platforms have one or more modern C compilers available to target, so you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. I might compile on mobile platforms, like android and ios.

Comment: @Appu: iOS certainly has C99 support.  I'm not certain about Android, but I would guess that it's supported in the NDK.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bad practice *not* to use C99 features where they are useful. C89 is long-obsolete, doing things like storing boolean values in ints or declaring all variables at the beginning of a function can be considered bad style now.

Forget about MSVC. MSVC is a C++ compiler and neither intended nor suitable for compiling C.